# How to make soap request for wcf service usind Zend\Soap\Client\DotNet?

Tags: php, wcf, web-services, zend-framework, soap

Below is my test code to access webservice using SOAP, The services are developed using .NET .

when executed the code I am getting exception
File:

```
...\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Soap\Client\DotNet.php:199
```

Message:

****.Net webservice arguments have to be grouped into array: array("a" => $a, "b" => $b, ...).****

```
public function testAction()
{
    $client = new DotNet(
                'http://ip/Services/SomeService.svc?wsdl', 
                 array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
                )
        );
        //var_dump($client->getFunctions());
        //var_dump($client->getOptions());

        var_dump($client->call('ValidateUser',array('customercode'=>'Cust','username'=>'Admin','passwork'=>'Admin')));
        die
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with parameter passing

redefine the code as follows

**var_dump($client->call('ValidateUser',array**(array('customercode'=>'Cust','username'=>'Admin','passwork'=>'Admin')))**);**